# Selecting all empty text fields in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.3

How can I find all text fields that have an empty value?

```
$(":text[value='']")
```

gives a JavaScript error

I know I can do `$(":text")`, iterate through and return all fields with `$(this).val()==''`

I am looking for a cleaner method and using JQuery 1.3.1
It has to work if the element originally had a value when the page was loaded, and then the user cleared it.  (`$("#elem").attr('value')` gives the original value in that place, though .val() works properly)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Latest Answer: Upgrade to 1.3.2

Here are various tests I ran via FireBug on http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Different jQuery versions are switched in at page-load with special greasemonkey scripts.

```
>>> jQuery.prototype.jquery
"1.3.2"
>>> jQuery(":text[value='']")
[input#jq-primarySearch]
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element 'text'.
>>> jQuery(":text[value=]").get()
[input#jq-primarySearch]

>>> jQuery.prototype.jquery
"1.3.1"
>>> jQuery(":text[value='']")
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: value='']
>>> jQuery(":text[value=]").get()
[input#jq-primarySearch]

>>> jQuery.prototype.jquery
"1.3"
>>> jQuery(":text[value='']");
Object length=1 prevObject=Object context=document
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element 'text'.
[Break on this error] undefined
>>> jQuery(":text[value=]").get()
[input#jq-primarySearch]
```

Note that 1.3 and 1.3.2 handle it properly ( albeit with Firefox sending an error ) but they still get the node right.

**Alternatively**:  you could use the `:text[value=]` notation, which appears to work everywhere I tried it. Its just a bit suspect thats all.

( Ignore my Previous rantings, they're all bollocks, not having a good day -_-)

Comment: So only 1.3.1 has this problem... Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've just tried this and worked fine for me:

```
$(":text[value=]")
```

I just removed single quotes in selector.

Comment: This seems to work for me too. Although, I'm not sure if it is 100% equivalent. I'm afraid that it might act as `$(":text[value]")` in some situation.

Answer (score 2):

You were close. There's no assignment in jQuery selectors, so you only need a single '=':

```
$(":text[value='']")
```

Comment: sorry, question edited to remove the extra '='. That gives me an error using jquery 1.3.1

Comment: Seems the issue is with passing an empty value to an attribute selector.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're  doing ngz, but this answer works for me. theres the potential though your empty values are getting removed from the dom :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me

```
$(":text:not([value])")
```

Comment: this does not give a Javascript error, but if the element originally had a value and the user cleared it, it will not be selected.

Comment: I had a feeling it may be problematic, as it only specifies the attribute and not the value.

Answer (score 1):

The following code does this:

1. Searches the form for inputfields and textareas
2. Checks if the text value is empty or not
3. gives the textfield/textarea a black background-color to prove this
   works

   ```
   $('form').find("input[type=text], input[type=password], textarea").each(function(ev)
   {

   if(!$(this).val())
   {
      $(this).css("background-color","black");
   }

   });
   ```

Answer (score -2):

Shot in the dark as I haven't tested it, but does this work:

```
$(":text:empty")
```

Comment: No, :empty will select all text fields, because it matches fields with no children