# To disable a send button if fields empty by jQuery

Tags: jquery, button

**How can you disable the send -button if there is one or more input -fields empty?**

**My attempt in pseudo-code**

```
if ( $("input:empty") ) {
    $("input:disabled") 
}
else 
  // enable the ask_question -button
```

I have been reading these articles without finding a right solution

1. [Official docs about empty](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/empty): this is like not relevant because it looks for all input -fields
2. [a thread about disabled -feature in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882406/jquery-disable-button-not-submit-until-field-validates-validation-plugin): this seems to be relevant
3. [to be able to test jQuery Firefox/terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635240/selecting-all-empty-text-fields-in-jquery): to get a testing environment would help me most

I use at the moment the following code. 
It contains one bug about the character `;`, but I cannot find it.

## #1

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ask_form").validate(){
        rules: {
            username {
                required: true,
                minlenghth: 2
            },
            email: {
                required: true;
                minlength: 6
            },
            password {
                required: true,                                                                                                                                    
                minlength: 6
            }
        } 
    });
}
```

## #2 Meder's code

I slighhtly modified Meder's code. It disables the `send` -button permanently so it has a bug too.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputs = $('input', '#ask_form'), empty = false;
    // can also use :input but it will grab textarea/select elements and you need to check for those..

    inputs.each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() == '' ) {
            empty = true;
            return;
        }
    });

    if ( empty ) {
        $('.ask_question').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // or true I believe.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var $submit = $("input[type=submit]");
if ( $("input:empty").length > 0 ) {
   $submit.attr("disabled","disabled");
} else {
   $submit.removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

Comment: Just make sure to put this in an onChange event or similar so it will fire each time a field is changed.

Comment: Your code does disable the buttons. However, it does disable buttons too when the fields are not empty. - **How do you read this `input:empty).length > 0` in English?** - My attempt to apply the given rule to the tag `input` which is empty such that its length is greater than zero. - This does not make sense to me, since my consideration leads to a contradiction.

Comment: I removed `.length > 0`, but the buttons remain disabled.

Comment: what this does is gets a collection of all the input elements that have no children, including text nodes. the `length` property just determines how many items are in the collection. if there are 0 items in the collection, the `length` will be 0. you can obviously be more specific in your selector, like `$("input.myInputs:empty")` but this should do the trick.

Comment: i updated my code so that if everything is ok but previously was not, the button becomes enabled again

Comment: Your code is still buggy: it does not disable any button this time. **Why did you changed `$("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled","disabled");` to ` $submit.attr("disabled","disabled");`?** - I run your code also with a modification of your last code to your old code, but the same problem persists.

Comment: look, masi, it's not going to work verbatim. i'm giving you the framework to build upon. you have to insert the selectors that are relevant to your system. i pulled out `var $submit = $("input[type=submit]");` so that I didn't have to repeat myself and also so that the collection is called only once, which will speed up the process.

Comment: if you want to go back and put in `$("input[type=submit]");` in place of `$submit` it will work the same. go for it.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)
[Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)
[Demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

Comment: Thank you for the links! I am using the code in the demo at the moment. There is one bug in my code of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = $('input', 'form#foo'), empty = false;
// can also use :input but it will grab textarea/select elements and you need to check for those..

inputs.each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == '' ) {
        empty = true;
        return;
    }
});

if ( empty ) {
    $('#el').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // or true I believe.
}
```

Comment: Your code has the same problem as Jason's. It disables the `send` -button permanently.

Answer (score -1):

Missing the closing, try this for example #1:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ask_form").validate(){
        rules: {
            username {
                required: true,
                minlenghth: 2
            },
            email: {
                required: true;
                minlength: 6
            },
            password {
                required: true,                                                                                                                                    
                minlength: 6
            }
        } 
    });
});
```