# No input without text in the text box

Tags: html, input

So I have this:

```
<form action="results.html" class="pure-form" accept-charset="unicode">
<input type="hidden" name="cx" value="017807894282691686756:y12pdghija8"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ie" value="utf-8" />
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="" size="50"/>
  <input type="submit" class="pure-button" src="" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

It works just fine, but is there a way to make the button not clickable if there is nothing in the text box? Or just making the button do some other action if you don't write anything in the text box? Basically just how google has it, if you don't have anything in the box it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You can use JavaScript to detect whether there is anything typed, and grey-out/hide the submit button if there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with JavaScript and the setInterval function. It'll look something like this:

```
<script>
 window.setInterval(function() {
  var length = document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value.length;
  document.getElementsByClassName('pure-button')[0].disabled = !length;
 }, 100);
</script>
```

It would be easier if you used ids.

Comment: Thank you, that was perfectly what I wanted. I tried the other ones as well, but they didn't work as fine as your does. People like you are the stars of the community :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easly with javascript (jQuery).

Check this answer: [disable submit button if inputs are empty with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482714/disable-submit-button-if-inputs-are-empty-with-jquery)