# Why does "[value='']" throw an exception in IE7 and ":not(:not([value='']))" does not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to select the option label (option with value "") from a select box through jQuery. I use the following selector:

```
$("[value='']");
```

This works in most browsers, however in IE7 it throws an exception. If I change it to the following (imho equivalent) selector, then it works fine:

```
$(":not(:not([value='']))");
```

I'd prefer not to use the latter, but can't think a of better equivalent of the prior.

### Edit:

jQuery version: 1.3.1.
Exception:
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Exception thrown and not caught
on

```
if(S==null){throw"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "+ab}
```

where

```
ab = "value='']"
```

### Test setup:

To ensure nothing of my other code caused the problem I have reproduced the error in the following situation:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                alert($("option[value='']").html());
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option value="">test</option>
            <option value="1">test1</option>
            <option value="2">test2</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Edit:

[Link to bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3990)

Comment: tell your jquery version

Comment: "it throws an exception" - What does it say?

Comment: @PiTheNumber actually you can turn on some lamps when the sun goes down. Just because you can't straight up change the how-to, doesn't mean you can't find a solution.

Comment: try jquery 1.7.1 . It has a whole bunch of bugs like this fixed.

Comment: You should upgrade to 1.3.2+ Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635240/selecting-all-empty-text-fields-in-jquery

Comment: Sadly, upgrading is not an option for me. :(

Comment: @MatthijsWessels, why not? you could add jQuery 1.7.1 and use `noconflict` to have it continue to use `1.3` for whatever backwards compatibility you need, and use the newer jQuery for general-purpose code.

Comment: @zzzzBov, hmm, it's thousands of lines of code we're talking about here. So I have to be 100% sure that nothing falls over. Is the following what you mean:`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">   
  var jQuery17 = jQuery.noConflict(true);   
</script>`?

Comment: @MatthijsWessels, if you're writing thousands of lines of JavaScript code for a single page, and worrying about jQuery dependencies, it sounds like you haven't organized your JS very well.

Comment: @zzzzBov, please, don't get me started. It's legacy and I have to deal with it. Every change I make, I try to improve something, while not breaking anything and taking a minimal amount of time.

Comment: @zzzzBov, anyway thanks for pointing the noconflict thing out for me. It might come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to recommend you to use the latest jQuery version, wich would solve your problem. But if you are using this version for a good reason you should try the following:

This should work in all browsers:

```
alert( jQuery( 'input[value=]' ) );
```

Tested with JSFiddle and no errors: http://jsfiddle.net/bobkruithof/WUVHj/

Comment: Thanks, seems that that will work, although I wonder if this will ever evaluate to "input[value]" which will return all elements with a value attribute. Btw, jsfiddle only let's me test against jQuery 1.3.2, where this bug is not present ([value=''] works fine). Nevertheless, I tested it in my test setup and your solution seems to work in 1.3.1.

Comment: AFAIK this will never evaluate to input[value], so you are safe :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should not give you any error. Try specifying the tag type also `$("input[value='']")` assuming that you don't have any other elements to search with `value` attribute.

Comment: "Didn't work" means you still get the same error or it does not select the right elements? What elements do you have?

Comment: Still throws the same error. I have reproduced it in a test setting with minimal elements. I will update the question with my test setting.